# Enabling Bold and Color with LPT parallel printer

Tags: linux, bash, printer, parallel-port

I know how to echo text to my HP Deskjet 420 printer on lubuntu with bash:

```
echo -e "line of text" > /dev/lp0
```

Is there a way to print text that is bold or in color? Should I echo some sort of escape command to the printer?

Thanks.

Comment: The conversion from ANSI-escaped text to pdf (currently performed by aha+wkhtmltopdf) seems like something 'enscript' or 'paps' should natively be able to do; try submitting a 'wishlist' bug with one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to echo bold or colored text in a terminal is to use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For example, try this:

> $ echo -e '\033[01;1mthis text will be bold\033[00;0m this will not'
>     **this text will be bold** this will not

The escape sequence `\033[01;1m` causes the following text to be **bold** and `\033[00;0m` turns all attributes off, so it goes back to normal.

See [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) for a nice list of the various escape sequences.

Unfortunately, `lp` does not know how to deal with this. It only knows how to print postscript files. We therefore need a way of turning the ANSI escape characters into formatted postscript. I was intrigued by this question so I [posted one of my own on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70450/22222) asking about ways of interpreting the ANSI escapes as postscript commands. The following is from the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70474/22222) I got there, please go upvote it!

You will need the following tools:

- `aha` : Ansi HTML Adapter, this program can translate ANSI escape codes to HTML.

  ```
  DESCRIPTION
         aha takes SGR-colored Input and prints W3C conform HTML-Code.
         aha  reads the Input from a file or stdin and writes HTML-Code
         to stdout.
  ```

  Install:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install aha
  ```
- `wkhtmltopdf` :  An HTML to PDF converter.

  ```
  Description
         Converts one or more HTML pages into a PDF document, not using
         wkhtmltopdf patched qt.
  ```

  Install:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
  ```

Now, put them all together. I will use this command whose output is shown in the image below:

```
echo -e '\033[01;1mbold\033[00;0m,not bold, and \033[32;1mgreen'
```

[image]

So, let's print it:

```
echo -e '\033[01;1mbold\033[00;0m,not bold, and \033[32;1mgreen' | 
      aha | wkhtmltopdf  - - | lpr
```

And that's it, that will print a nice, formatted bold and colored line of text.

Comment: It makes me feel very old that someone wouldn't know about those straight away. :)

Comment: I think it has more to do with your general geekiness than your age :)

Comment: @terdon I'm sure that it's some sort of escape code. I made a quick bash script to see what sort of characters it can print and its an odd set of 256 characters that aren't bash. Used \x and hex (ex. \x9e ) and it is very different from Lubuntu's bash characters for those same values.

Comment: For example, \x1 is a smiley face, and \xc is a page break. Don't see that much in bash :)

Comment: @BlueIce sorry but I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about :). But hang on, I've found out how to do this, I will be posting an updated answer soon.

Comment: @BlueIce OK, I get what you mean, it is actually the same thing `\033` and `\x` are both `ESC`. Anyway, have a look at the updated answer and go upvote the very nice answer on U&L that gave it to me :).

Comment: @terdon All right. I'll test it out.